# Android Read-Only File System Error

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, ioexception, readonly

Hi I have a gallery in my app which shows the image in an image view when you click on the thumbnail. I am setting up a Long Click Listener for an alert dialog that has 2 buttons one to set as wallpaper and one to share. I have the share intent and the get drawing cache somewhat working. It works in the emulator but not on my phone. I have used many of the examples on this site to get this going but its not working at all. it keeps force closing the app on my phone. any help is appreciated.

```
                                alertDialog.setButton2("Share",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            imgView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            Bitmap b = imgView.getDrawingCache();
                            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                            File file = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "image.jpg");

                            try {
                                file.createNewFile();
                                OutputStream fos = null;
                                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                                fos.flush();
                                fos.close();
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Log.d("Save Example", "Image saved.");

                            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            Uri phototUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image.jpg");
                            shareIntent.setData(phototUri);
                            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, phototUri);
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via"));
                        }

                    });

            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Update: it seems to be a problem with

```
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, fos);
```

it keeps saying null pointer.

Turns out the null pointer is actually a read_only error..So its not actually writing the file i get a  ioexception read-only file system. Why is it doing this?

Comment: You need to look at the permissions of the directory before you try writing. You have to understand basic file system permissions from UNIX to do this analysis.

Comment: are you using write permission in manifest file ??

Comment: yes I have write.external.storage in the manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here s what i ended up doing to get this to share the pictures in case others need it. It turns out my ImageView was not being rendered as a BitMap so it was make files with nothing in them. So instead i am just calling the drawable from its postion and saving that. Its a lot cleaner code for this simple gallery. I have it in an alert dialog but it can be set to a regular button also.

```
                alertDialog.setButton2("Share",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            imgView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            String newFolder = "/CFW";
                            String extStorageDirectory = Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    .toString();
                            File sdCard = new File(extStorageDirectory
                                    + newFolder);
                            sdCard.mkdir();

                            File file = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()
                                    + "/cfw" + currentTime + ".jpg");

                            try {
                                InputStream is = getResources()
                                        .openRawResource(pics[position]);
                                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
                                is.read(data);
                                os.write(data);
                                is.close();
                                os.close();
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Log.d("Save Example", "Image saved.");

                            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            Uri photoUri = Uri
                                    .parse("file:///sdcard/CFW/cfw"
                                            + currentTime + ".jpg");
                            shareIntent.setData(photoUri);
                            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                    photoUri);
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,
                                    "Share Via"));
                        }

                    });

            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```